# Sybase SQL split comma delimited column into multiple rows

Tags: sql, sybase

I am trying to split a Column based on a semi colon:

Currently I have the following:
[image]

And I want to see this:
[image]

I see several solutions on the site but they do not seem to be working for sybase sql

Comment: Out of curiosity, why isn't your data normalized in the first-place?

Comment: Not a sybase user, but a quick search for "sybase split string into rows" shows it _may_ have a function called `sa_split_list`. Not sure if you need to create that function.

Comment: Sybase (the company) had 4x different RDBMS products (ASE, IQ, SQLAnywhere, Advantage).  Which Sybase RDBMS product (and version) are you using? what are a couple of the queries you've tried that you state *`do not seem to be working`*, and how are they not working (errors? wrong results? no results? something else?).

Comment: you state *`split a Column based on a semi colon`* but the 2nd column appears to be comma-delimited; please update the question to insure sample data matches the description; also, the input shows lowercase letters but the expected result shows all uppercase letters, please update the question to confirm that you also want to uppercase all characters